# How to do vectorization for summation for octave implementation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectorization

I am trying to understand the transformation from a summation form to vectorization (or a form of matrix multiplications) in order to implement it in some programming language (octave or python or whatever) without using for loops.

The expression that I want to vectorize is this

[image]

The document that I got this form from tried to explain the process
[image]

So far this is clear except for (1) which the document tried to explain it like this:

[image]

I felt confused because what I know from matrix multiplication is to multiply a row by a column. I cannot understand this step where the multiplication here is like multiplying a column by a row.

Could you explain the last step a little further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think a column vector as an element of the matrix. Let me explain with a simple example.

Support the $A$ is a 3 by 3 matrix and $\vec{a_i}$ is its $i$th column vector.

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{a_1} & \vec{a_2} & \vec{a_3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some 3-dimensional vector $\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix} x & y & z \end{bmatrix} $,

$$
\begin{align}
&A\vec{x}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
ax + by + cz \\
dx + ey + fz \\
gx + hy + iz
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
ax \\ dx \\ gx
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
by \\ ey \\ hy
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
cz \\ fz \\ iz
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=x\vec{a_1} + y\vec{a_2} + z\vec{a_3} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{a_1} & \vec{a_2} & \vec{a_3}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{a_1} & \vec{a_2} & \vec{a_3}
\end{bmatrix}
*
\vec{v}
\end{align}
$$